# Execute code in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc

I'm using the subprocess module to start a subprocess (java program) and connect to it's output stream (stdout). I tried to execute the following code in a class and it run sucessfully, but when i try to execute it in a thread something weird happen, the program does not work.

```
class MiThread(threading.Thread,QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):  
      def __init__(self):  
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)   

      def run(self):

        print "si se puede"
        try:
            from Queue import Queue, Empty
        except ImportError:
    #from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x
            print "error"

        ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        p= Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/',stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize= 4024)
        q = Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        #t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        print "estoy en el hilo"
        t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        t.start()

# ... do other things here
        while True:

            try: line = q.get_nowait()
         # or q.get(timeout=.1)
            except Empty:
                print('')
            else: # got line
    # ... do something with line
                print "No esta null"
                print line
```

class Workspace(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """ This class is for managing the whole GUI `Workspace'.
        Currently a Workspace is similar to a MainWindow
    """

```
 def __init__(self):

         #Llamar al hilo secundario
        t= MiThread()
        t.start()
```

i would like to execute it in a thread! 
PLease help!

Comment: Please show where you create a `MiThread` instance and call its `start()` method (if you don't have this anywhere, that may be the problem).

Comment: Along with the first comment what errors if any occur?